# How to transition width when text changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a text fade in fade out transition effect as such:

```js
let change = document.querySelector("#change")
let transition_duration = 2000

let title = ["a plane!", "Superman!", "a bird!"]
let i = 0

setInterval(async() => {
  change.style.transitionDuration = (transition_duration / 2000) + 's'
  change.classList.add("fadeout")

  setTimeout(() => {
    change.classList.remove("fadeout")
    change.innerText = title[i];
    i = (i + 1) % title.length
  }, transition_duration / 2);

}, 3000)
```

```css
#change {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  transition: all;
}

.fadeout {
  color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
It's <span id="change">a bird!</span>
```

But as you can see the width does not transition when the text changes the length of the `<span>`
is there fix for this?

Comment: try to add `width: 100%;` at `.fadeout`

Comment: @DSDmark nope that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Yogi the timers are for customizability incase someone needs to change the value in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how you want to animate the width. Based on your code you expect it animated when the text is changed, not ahead, so the solution.

Also you have an useless `async`.

The width should be explicitly set and takes effects when you span is `display:inline-block`. To make it line up with the rest of the text you could use `vertical-align:middle` (it's `base` by default).

To avoid text overflowing when width changes to bigger you need `overflow:hidden`.
To get a right width with paddings you could set `box-sizing:border-box`. Also set `white-space:nowrap` so in this case the text won't break on a new line.

To center the text during the animation place it in an inner span with `margin: 0 -100%`.

To calc the next width you should set the span to `inline` and set the next title temporarily.

```js
let change=document.querySelector("#change")
let transition_duration=2000

let title=["a plane!", "Superman!", "a bird!" ]
let i=0

change.innerHTML = `<span>${change.textContent}</span>`;
change.style.width = change.offsetWidth + 'px';

setInterval(()=>{

  change.style.transitionDuration=(transition_duration/2000) + 's'
  change.classList.add("fadeout")
  const prevTitle = change.innerText;
  i=(i + 1)%title.length;
  change.style.display='inline';
  change.innerText=title[i];
  const widthTo = change.offsetWidth;
  change.style.display='inline-block';
  change.innerText=prevTitle;
 
  setTimeout(()=>{
     console.log(widthTo);
     change.style.width = widthTo + 'px';
     change.classList.remove("fadeout");
     change.innerHTML = `<span>${title[i]}</span>`;
     
  },transition_duration/2);

},3000)
```

```css
#change{
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:3px;
  color:white;
  transition: all;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;

}
#change span {
  margin: 0 -100%;
}

.fadeout{
  color:transparent !important;
}
```

```html
It's <span id="change">a bird!</span>
```

A solution with width animation during all the transition.

Here we could actually use `async` to wait for the next animation frame. Also we cound use a css animation instead of a transition:

```js
const change=document.querySelector("#change")
const duration=2000

const title=["a plane!", "Superman!", "a bird!" ]
let i=0


change.style.transition = `width ${duration}ms, color ${duration/2}ms`;
change.innerHTML = `<span>${change.textContent}</span>`;
change.style.width = change.offsetWidth + 'px';

setInterval(async ()=>{

  change.style.animation = '';
  const prevTitle = change.innerText;
  i=(i + 1)%title.length;
  change.style.display='inline';
  change.innerText=title[i];
  const widthTo = change.offsetWidth;
  change.style.display='inline-block';
  change.innerText=prevTitle;
  
  await new Promise(r=>requestAnimationFrame(r));
  console.log(widthTo);
  change.style.width = widthTo + 'px';
  change.style.animation =`fade ${duration}ms`;

  setTimeout(()=>{
     change.innerHTML = `<span>${title[i]}</span>`;
  },duration/2);

},3000)
```

```css
#change{
  display:inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:3px;
  color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;

}
#change span {
  margin: 0 -100%;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,100% { color: white; }
  50% { color: transparent; }
}
```

```html
It's <span id="change">a bird!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation transition needs an explicit initial and ending value.
`width` needs to have an explicit value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a smooth transition effect with the changing text length, you can utilize CSS keyframe animations instead of manipulating the transition-duration property. Here's an updated version of your code that includes the width transition:

```js
const change = document.querySelector("#change");
    const title = ["a plane!", "Superman!", "a bird!"];
    let i = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
      change.classList.add("fadeout");

      setTimeout(() => {
        change.classList.remove("fadeout");
        change.innerText = title[i];
        i = (i + 1) % title.length;
      }, 500); 

    }, 2000);
```

```css
#change {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  animation: fade 4s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0; /* Add initial opacity */
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%, 20% { opacity: 0; } /* Start and end with opacity 0 */
  25%, 75% { opacity: 1; } /* Fully visible */
  80%, 100% { opacity: 0; } /* Fade out */
}

.fadeout {
  animation: none !important;
}
```

```html
It's <span id="change">a bird!</span>
```